# Removing attachments from Zend_Mail object

Tags: php, zend-framework

is there any way to remove an attachment from Zend_Mail object? Simple
example:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();

//..configuring the email..

$mail->createAttachment($myImage,
                        'image/gif',
                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
$mail->send();
```

now, I would like to modify the object and send it again

```
$mail->clearSubject()
     ->setSubject('new subject');
```

is there any posibility to remove the attachment from this object that
was set previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->createAttachment("...");

$parts = $mail->getParts();
foreach ($parts as $k => $v) {
    if ($v->disposition == "attachment") {
        unset($parts[$k]);
    }
}
$mail->setParts($parts);
$mail->hasAttachments = false;
```

This will only remove parts where their MIME disposition is set to **attachment**.

Comment: So if `$parts = array()`, `$mail->_parts` will be set to `NULL`.

Comment: But it's initialized to `array()` in ZF source code and `addPart()` sets `$this->_parts[] = $part;` without checking for `null` condition

Comment: True, I thought it was set to null, just edited my answer, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of is

```
$mail->setParts(array());
```

But this will remove all parts, whatever they might be.